# Extract objects from cvFindContour

Tags: c++, opencv, contour

I am able to draw some contours using cvFindContour on my webcam's capture but now I would like to store each contour into some object.

The goal here is to make a live object detection on a camera's capture but I really have no idea what to do with these contours.

Any ideas please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I would like to store each contour into some object*

Well if you do something like this:

```
// detect edges using canny:
Mat edges;
Canny(myImg, edges, 100, 200, 3);

vector<vector<Point> > contours;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
findContours(edges, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
```

after the `findContours` call the `contours` vector holds your contours already.

> *I really have no idea what to do with these contours*

This is completely different question that is very specific for your concrete domain, concrete approach... No one can tell you what exactly you ***should*** do, but you can research about some existing solutions and learn more about the current state of art to find out what you ***could*** do. You need to do it on your own :)

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply.
I am already able to find and draws contours. It is stored into a CvSeq* but what if I want to display only the contour number X for instance ? 
All I can do is CvSeq* contours->h_next :s

Comment: @kevinlabille: That's why I attached that example of how it should look like. You're using C++, so don't use old C-style OpenCV functions. In my example you have nice `std::vector` object with contours.